# Save Checkbox state in a Panel/Dialog

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, dialog

I am new to swings and I have one doubt:

I have one dialog box, in that dialog, there is one Check Box, Ok and Cancel buttons.
suppose user selected checkbox and click ok button, when user opens again that dialog box, the check box should be as selected.

can anyone give idea, how to implment this.

I know I can do this by using setSelected(true) and setSelected(false) methods.

but how to save the state of the check box.

Comment: Top of my head: Save to DB, Write/Parse as text (properties file, xml, json, raw txt), Read/Write Object to file, or use Java Preferences

Comment: Keep a reference to the original dialog.  When the time comes, set it visible again, and it will have the same size and position, and each control in it will have the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass components to the `JOptionPane` and they will be displayed properly.

So for example if you create a `JCheckBox` and pass it to the `JOptionPane`, after the dialog is closed, you can examine the state of the check box and store it anywhere you'd like to. Next time you want to display the dialog, before passing the check box, set its state to the one you stored last time.

For example (just for demonstration purposes):

```
final JFrame f = new JFrame("Checkbox test");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    // I store the checkbox state here in a boolean variable:
    boolean save;

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // Now user wants to close the application, ask confirmation:
        // We create a check box with the initial value of the stored state:
        JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Save settings before Exit", save);
        int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            new Object[] {"Are you sure you want to Exit?", cb}, "Exit?",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        // Dialog closed, you can save the sate of the check box
        save = cb.isSelected();
        if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if (save) {
                // Settings can be saved here.
            }
            // And exit (by disposing the only frame)
            f.dispose();
        }
    }
});
f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Try to close the application"));
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: please without wrapping into `while (true) {` (endless loop with `true` ???) to make me sence

Comment: @mKorbel The endless loop was just to show the dialog again automatically if it is closed with `Cancel` so the user can see the checkbox is in the same state it was last time. Reworked the example to use `JFrame` instead.

Comment: thx a lot @icza. But when I check the checkbox **save**, click cancel, call the JOptionPane again I see that **save** is still checked. Should **save** not reset his state and only save it when I click **OK**?

Comment: @okaisan1 The purpose of the example is exactly how to make the checkbox visible on the dialog **retain/remember** its value if the dialog is closed and reopened. The example is not about how to persist and load settings.